# What is the gnuchess 5.60 "real" rating?

Tags: engines

Anyone can say me what is the gnuchess 5.60 "real" rating with a Atom 1.2GHZ and 2GB RAM 32Bits? or something approximate...

According to CCRL, gnuchess 5.60 elo is 2822 ! this website inflate the elo rating
of chess engines.

Comment: It sounds like you doubt 2822 could be an accurate rating only because you *believe* you will beat it at some point in the near future. Is that right?

Comment: Be sure to give it about 3 minutes per move, which is about tournament speed.

Answer (score 1):

Computer rating is relative and has no relation to the Human FIDE. It's over 2800 in CCRL, it could be something else on the FIDE scale. The rating reported is only valid for the specific conditions used by CCRL. Nobody knows for sure the "real" rating on your machine.